# No break in SwipeRefreshLayout.java in android 5 onInterceptTouchEvent module

Tags: android, motionevent, swiperefreshlayout

I notice in that function there are no break after Action_down, then code can run into ACTION_MOVE, is that right?

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    ensureTarget();

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    if (mReturningToStart && action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mReturningToStart = false;
    }

    if (!isEnabled() || mReturningToStart || canChildScrollUp() || mRefreshing) {
        // Fail fast if we're not in a state where a swipe is possible
        return false;
    }

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom(mOriginalOffsetTop - mCircleView.getTop(), true);
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
            mIsBeingDragged = false;
            final float initialMotionY = getMotionEventY(ev, mActivePointerId);
            if (initialMotionY == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            mInitialMotionY = initialMotionY;
           //-------NO Break here, why? It will run down to ACTION_MOVE
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mActivePointerId == INVALID_POINTER) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Got ACTION_MOVE event but don't have an active pointer id.");
                return false;
            }
            final float y = getMotionEventY(ev, mActivePointerId);
            if (y == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            final float yDiff = y - mInitialMotionY;
            if (yDiff > mTouchSlop && !mIsBeingDragged) {
                mIsBeingDragged = true;
                mProgress.setAlpha(STARTING_PROGRESS_ALPHA);
            }
            break;

        case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            onSecondaryPointerUp(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            mIsBeingDragged = false;
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
            break;
    }

    return mIsBeingDragged;
}
```

I do not know why treat ACTION_DOWN then directly to treat ACTION_MOVE, Is this right?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Just noticed this in my logs today, good spot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I post a bug report at google code, it is accepted to the future release.
[No break in SwipeRefreshLayout.java in android 5 onInterceptTouchEvent module](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78106)

Comment: I still have this issue in my code. Where is this change included?